# fdisk -l not showing USB drive

Tags: 12.10, usb

I ran `fdisk -l` then I connected my USB drive to my computer and ran `fdisk -l` again but the list of drives didn't change at all.

What can I do?

Comment: first check lspci and see if it appears.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing `lspci` for an USB drive? I assume you meant `lsusb`.

Comment: correct.  i was having a moment

Answer (score 0):

plug the USB in, and run in terminal:

```
$ lsusb > 1
```

unplug the USB, and run:

```
$ lsusb > 2
```

And follow by this:

```
$ diff 1 2
```

What output do you get?